# How to safely retrieve ArrayList from Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, generics

How do I safely retrieve an ArrayList object from Map where the value stored for the key is an ArrayList. Below is my code. Is there any other way to do it instead of the cast to ArrayList?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A"); list.add("B");

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("list", list);
    System.out.println(map.get("list").getClass()); // class java.util.ArrayList
    List<String> l = (ArrayList<String>)map.get("list");
}
```

Comment: Do not store an arraylist in a map that stores objects. Instead, tell the map to store arraylists (or lists). Do not throw away type information that you still need. This indicates that you have a bad architecture that should be redesigned instead of trying to make the cast safe.

Comment: @Zabuza has given you good advice.

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>` is a thing that you can do.

Comment: Apart from that, you _could_ do `if` with `instanceof` to check if a cast is safe. But as said, the need for that usually indicates bad design.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. This is what I get back after Jackson de-serializes a big object I get in a REST Call. Some of the members of the object are arrays. I get a dynamic object in the Rest call and my model object is defined as ```public class Element extends HashMap<String, Object>```

Comment: If you are stuck with `Map<String, Object>` there is nothing you can do other than casting

Comment: @werries1978 Hi, I also stuck in the same problem. I am using the `@JsonAnySetter` from `Jackson` to store the `Map<String, Object>` now my `Object` element has a couple of values something like this `[MainValue3, MainValue3]` and when I check the `class` they are of `class java.util.ArrayList`. (Same exact situation as you have explained in the question). I am unable to change the type of my `Map` as I need it to be `Objet` can you please let me know what you did to retrieve the values within the `Object`? I am struggling for about half a day to find the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `@JsonAnySetter` from `Jackson` to store the `Map<String, Object>`. When I checked the class they are of class `java. util.ArrayList`. (Same exact situation as explained in the question).

After trying few things I was able to get it. I know I am a bit late but hopefully, it will be helpful to someone in the future:

I had the `Map<String, Object>` the `Object` was storing either another `Map`, `String`, or `ArrayList` so I did the following things to get the values from my `Map`. You can use this as a reference and based on your required type you can do different things.

```
public void marshal(Map<String, Object> extensions) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : extensions.entrySet()) {
       if (property.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
            for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<String>) property.getValue()) {
                 if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
                    //do whatever you want to do Map type
                  } else if(dupItems instanceof String) {
                    //do whatever you want to do for String type
                  }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```